# Plotting simple implicit equations

Tags: plot

I would like to plot the graph of a simple equation like x^2+xy+2y^2=1 using TikZ. There are some posts on implicit plots here, but nothing worked in my case.

I am using TeXShop Version 3.92 and `\documentclass{book}`.

Comment: What does nothing worked mean? What have you tried so far? Please add a MWE. You might want to have a look at pgfplots.

Comment: I tried what is proposed in 18359 and got an error message. The method proposed in 18359 worked, but I was not able to modify it to work for the type of equations like the one in my question. The example given in 285246, which I liked the most, texed without any problems, but then I got an empty page.

Comment: did you enable shell-escape as in 285246 ?

Comment: My preferences do not look like what they show.  The closest thing is Pdftex under Default Script.  There are no additional options. It is checked.

Answer (score 3):

## Question 18359

The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18384/16967) of [question 18359](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18359/16967) works for me. Changed line:

```
splot x^2 + x*y + 2*y^2 - 1;
```

And I added the line

```
set samples 500;
```

for a smoother curve.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot +[no markers,
      raw gnuplot,
      thick,
      empty line = jump % not strictly necessary, as this is the default behaviour in the development version of PGFPlots
      ] gnuplot {
      set contour base;
      set cntrparam levels discrete 0.003;
      unset surface;
      set view map;
      set isosamples 500;
      set samples 500;
      splot x^2 + x*y + 2*y^2 - 1;
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This solution requires that [gnuplot](http://gnuplot.info/) is installed and available on the command line. Depending on the TeX configuration (`texmf.cnf` in TeX Live), usually option `-shell-escape` (TeX Live)/`-enable-write18` (MiKTeX) for the TeX compiler is needed to run the example, see the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405305/plotting-simple-implicit-equations#comment1010187_405305) of Sari.

> [image: Result]

## Question 285246

The example of [question 285246](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285246/16967) also works with the following function:

```
f(x,y) = x**2 + x*y + 2*y**2 - 1;
```

(x<sup>2</sup> is expressed as `x**2`.)

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw plot[id=question1, raw gnuplot] function{
    f(x,y) = x**2 + x*y + 2*y**2 - 1;
    set xrange [-4:4];
    set yrange [-4:4];
    set view 0,0;
    set isosample 1000, 1000;
    set size square;
    set contour base;
    set cntrparam levels incre 0,0.1,0;
    unset surface;
    splot f(x,y);
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I just can't get the ellipse in my TeXShop Version 3.92.  I tried to enable shell-escape, but for some reason it does not seem to work.

Comment: @PiotrMikusinski Check the `.log` file, it should contain something like `runsystem(gnuplot test.pgf-plot.gnuplot)...executed.`.

Comment: I found this in my log file: \openout3 = `"DAPM-13-SA-Quadratic forms.question1.gnuplot"'.

runsystem(gnuplot "DAPM-13-SA-Quadratic forms.question1.gnuplot")...executed.

Comment: @PiotrMikusinski That means that shell escape is working. Now, check the console output for errors, e.g. `system returned with code 256`. Unhappily, this is not written to the `.log` file. I do not know, whether TeXShop is able to catch it. Therefore, it is better to run on the command line, e.g. `pdflatex -shell-escape test` and check the messages on the screen.

Comment: I also get this:
Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `Ellipse.question1.table' not found. on input line 20.
This is what I got when I run "pdflatex -shell-escape test": This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `test'.
<*> test

Comment: @PiotrMikusinski That means, the `gnuplot` command did not succeed (the output file was not generated). Before the warning there can be a message, warning, error with the reason. Further tests: `gnuplot --version` should print the version number of gnuplot. Also, there should be a file `Ellipse.question1.gnuplot`, the source code for gnuplot. Test: `gnuplot Ellipse.question1.gnuplot` on the command line.

Comment: Finally I found something that worked for me (I used more mathematics than LATEX):    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis,
            xmin=-2,xmax=2,
            ymin=-2,ymax=2,
            ]
            \addplot [blue,thick,domain=0:360,samples=200]({(cos(x)+sin(x)},{sin(x)}); 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % It is based on tikz!
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[
surf,
samples=20,
domain=-100:100,
y domain=-100:100
] 
{x^2+x*y+2*y^2-1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what I asked for in my question (I asked for the equation x^2+xy+2y^2=1 that gives us an ellipse), but I may need the 3d version too.  Can we get the surface without the axes?

Comment: Oh really, sorry:((((

Comment: If you don't want axes, then you should use `hide axis` option of `axis` environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis,xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2,]
    \addplot [blue,thick,domain=0:360,samples=200]({(cos(x)+sin(x)},{sin(x)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: The above graphs the equation x^2-2xy+2y^2=1, which is not the equation in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a not-tikz solution, the `mfpic` package, interface to the MetaPost language, seems to work quite well in this kind of problem with its `\levelcurve` command.

```
\documentclass[border=3bp]{standalone}
\usepackage[metapost, mplabels, truebbox]{mfpic}
  \setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
  \opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfpic}[2]{-1.5}{1.5}{-1.5}{1.5}
  \drawcolor[gray]{0.7}
  \gridlines{.5,.5}
  \drawcolor{black}
  \levelcurve{origin, .01}{x**2 + x*y + 2(y**2) < 1}
  \doaxes{xy}
  \tlpointsep{3bp}
  \tlabels{[tc]{(-1, 0)}{$-1$} [tc]{(1, 0)}{$1$} [tc]{(\xmax, 0)}{$x$}}
  \tlabels{[cr]{(0, -1)}{$-1$} [cr]{(0, 1)}{$1$} [cr]{(0, \ymax)}{$y$}}
\end{mfpic}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

With TeXShop, process this TeX file with (PDF)LaTeX, then with MetaPost, and finally with LaTeX again.

[image]

See the [`mfpic` documentation](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/graphics/mfpic/doc/mfpic-doc.pdf) p.44-45 for more information on this most useful command.